# get stylelint report by broken rule instead of filename

Tags: css, sass, stylelint

I have implemented [STYLELINT](https://stylelint.io/) in my project.

But currently this shows error by file name.

```
fileone.scss
Line 10:5 expected this 'rule-xyz'
Line 15:5 expected this 'rule-abc'
Line 25:5 expected this 'rule-123'

anotherfile.scss
Line 12:5 expected this 'rule-xyz'
Line 18:5 expected this 'rule-abc'
Line 26:5 expected this 'rule-123'
```

Is there any way one get error sorted by broken rules instead of filename?? like below?

```
rule-xyz
file-one.scss Line 10:5 expected bla bla
file-two.scss Line 19:5 expected bla bla
file-three.scss Line 30:5 expected bla bla

rule-abc
file-one.scss Line 10:5 expected bla bla
file-two.scss Line 19:5 expected bla bla
file-three.scss Line 30:5 expected bla bla
```

**I checked on their website but couldn't find any answer.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in formatter that lists the violations *grouped by rule*.

There are other options, though:

1. The built-in verbose formatter (`stylelint "**/*.css" --formatter verbose`) produces a *tally* of violations for each rule.
2. The built-in json formatter (`stylelint "**/*.css" --formatter json`) produces a `json` output. By using external charting libraries, one can see data in graph format as well.
3. Custom formatters are supported by stylelint, via the `--custom-formatter` CLI flag. So, it is possible to [write your own formatter](https://stylelint.io/developer-guide/formatters/) to list the violations exactly as you want.

Comment: Also see [stylelint-formatter-stats](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stylelint-formatter-stats) for an example of a custom formatter that groups results by rule.

Comment: Voted up. Thanks @jeddy3 atleast it gives me summary of broken rules. Will keep it open for a while.